# editing a windows command file with Aptana

Tags: aptana

On windows XP, running Apatana Studio 3.

How do I open a windows command (i.e. *.bat) file for editing rather than executing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ProjectExplorer pane, you can right click a .cmd or .bat file and select [Open With > TextEditor].

Aptana "remembers" this setting, so double clicking this file in the ProjectExplorer pane will continue to open the file for editing.

To go back to execute mode, right-click again but select [Open With > Default Editor].  That's a horrible choice of labelling - i.e. Aptana's Default Editor for .cmd,.bat files actually runs them - it doesn't edit them.

If anyone reading knows a better way, pls comment.